# how to share data using nsobject class(in watch OS 2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I am creating a watchApp using my existing iOS App.In my iOS App i have a class (.h and .m) and ,i am setting the target membership of .m to 
WatchApp Extension.
I'm getting is `SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h` file not found error for some `AFNetworking` classes(`Reachability.h`).
and i know the  `SystemConfiguration.framework` no longer support in watchos2.

Answer (score 0):

The SystemConfiguration framework is not supported in WatchOS,
please check: 
[Can I build my own networking framework (which is dependent on AFNetworking) as a watchOS2 framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324001/can-i-build-my-own-networking-framework-which-is-dependent-on-afnetworking-as)